# Why both "was" and "were" in this sentence?

Tags: american-english

Why both "was" and "were" in this sentence? Grammarly checker suggests again "was" instead "were". What is right?

Here is the sentence:

> Michael’s actions, Michael’s frenzy was and were absurd.

Here is the context:

> Whose actions were absurd?
>
> Michael’s actions, Michael’s actions were absurd.
>
> Were Michael’s actions calm and logical? Or were they absurd?
>
> They were absurd. **Michael’s actions, Michael’s frenzy was and were
> absurd.** Jeff said,  “Michael, this is absurd. Just buy a wig. ”

([The Effortless English Club, Automatic English For The People, Small Is Beautiful Mini-Story Text](https://archive.org/stream/EffortlessEN_Courses/Effortless%20English%20Courses/Power%20English/Power%20English%20Text%20Files/17%20Small%20Is%20Beautiful%20Text/Small%20Is%20Beautiful%20MS%20Text_djvu.txt))

Comment: That sentence makes no sense. Did you mean "was and is"?

Comment: I just read that in A. J. Hoge's lesson.

Comment: I just googled "was and were absurd" and "A. J. Hoge" and found that the complete sentence is *Were Michael’s actions calm and logical? Or were they absurd?* // *They were absurd. **Michael’s actions, Michael’s frenzy was and were absurd.***. That is, what you have provided is nonsensical because you only provided a fragment of the sentence. When you ask English questions, you *must* provide the complete context or at best people will not be able to answer you (as in this case), or will provide completely misleading or wrong answers at worse.

Comment: Uh uh, my fault, @DanBron thank you very very much. I would like give you the bounty (it is from my reputation if I understand).

Comment: @b2ok Thank you for the offer, but no bounty is needed. It turns out I can't spend my reputation on fast cars or big yachts, so I've stopped worrying about building it up ;)

Comment: @DanBron: Good find. The grammar still doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Thank you @sumelic very much for editing. Now, after commenting of DanBron and your editing, I have the excellent answer.

Comment: @DonBron :) :) :) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Michael's frenzy was absurd" is a valid sentence, but "Michael's frenzy were absurd" is not. Therefore, "Michael's frenzy was and were absurd" is not correct.

*Were* is only used in two situations:

- Plural subjects in the past tense, as in "We were eating"
- Hypothetical (what if) situations, as in "If Michael's frenzy were absurd, we could ignore it."

Comment: So you're saying "Michael's frenzy were absurd" is absurd?

Comment: Note: I edited the question to correct the quoted sentence. This may provide a reason to edit your answer; sorry about that.